.AspNetCore.Cookies is not shared from Visual Studio debug mode into another browser window
I use authentication .AspNetCore.Cookies cookie. If I run the asp.net core web from VS in debug mode, the authentication challenge is started and I need to log in. After login the .AspNetCore.Cookies is created. Then I open new browser (Chrome) window and paste manualy the base URL address of the application. But the .AspNetCore.Cookies is not present in the new window and the application wants another login.
After my investigation it seems that the debug mode uses different cookie storage. The cookies created in both window are different and are not compatible between browser windows. So the main purpose - Single Sign On - does not work as expected.
After creating new cookie in non debug window, then the SSO with other new opened browser windows works great.
I don't understand the difference between debug mode and non-debug mode.
Do you have same experience or is this a normal behavior?

Hi AldaFalda, are you using same browser ? I mean using Chrome browser only. Another things, we need to confirm that have you change IsPersistent properties or not.

Yes, I'm using same browser (Chrome) only. The IsPersistent property is set to True.

Thanks for your reply, please share the launchSettings.json file and Program.cs,  we need to check the settings, it may also can help us to reproduce the issue. Please hide your sensitive if any.

Which part of Program.cs are you interested in? There is a lot of extension methods in the Program.cs and it's not easy to share it all.

Hi AldaFalda, I want to check  .AddAuthentication and cookie related.

Hello Jason, it seems the problem is with Chrome. I checked it with Firefox now and it works as expected. I don't know why, but VS runs the Chrome in anonymous mode. Even I'm signed into google account in another Chrome window, VS opens Chrome without my credentials and indicates "Person 1 - Not signed in". It seems that cookies are stored per account in Chrome.

Thanks for your sharing, @AldaFalda, have a nice day.
